# C++ Ключевое слово 'and' vs оператор '&&' и похожие операторы

Tags: c++, style-guide, keyword

На практике в IT-компаниях используют для операндов ключевые слова или операторы? Google C++ Style не затрагивает эту тему.  Мои рассуждения: ключевые слова улучшают читабельность кода, также помогают понять код людям, владеющим только знанием псевдокода.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main() {
  if ((true or false) and (1 || 0)) std::cout << "Equivalently\n";
}
```

Comment: Это называется [Alternative operator representations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) Да, используют. И еще отмечу, что `1` не является эквивалентом `true`.

Comment: Мы используем только операторы -- `&&, ||, ! ...` и т.п.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, используют - у нас в компании такой гайдлайн. С плюсами согласен, минусов не вижу. Ещё один неупомянутый плюс (и изначальная мотивация таких операторов) - это большая портабельность за счёт того, что их могут использовать люди без значков | и &.